# Como habilita cordova.plugins.notification.local Visual Studio cordova?

Tags: visual-studio, apache-cordova, visual-studio-2017, cordova-plugin

Adicionei o link github "https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications" e instalou o plugin perfeitamente.
Coloquei um botao e no evento click dele coloquei o seguinte código:

```
<script>
function abrir(){
    cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
        title: 'My first notification',
        text: 'Thats pretty easy...',
        foreground: true
    });
}
</script>
```

No Html tenho:

```
<button onclick="abrir()">Teste</button>
```

Tenho que habilitar algo no celular para permitir disparar notificação?Porque quando clico no botao nada acontece